# git ls-remote returns "fatal: No remote configured to list refs from."

Tags: git, ls-remote

```
$ git ls-remote
```

results in

```
fatal: No remote configured to list refs from.
```

I have remotes defined

```
$ git remote
```

results in

```
personal_remote
upstream
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can get this behavior in repos that have no `origin` remote.  You can supply an alternate default remote name by setting `remote.pushDefault`.

Comment: @jthill correctly points out that `ls-remote` is expecting a remote with the name `origin`.  The solution is to either rename one of the remotes to `origin` or use `remote.pushDefault` to tell `ls-remote` which to use.

Answer (score 5):

We can provide remote in the command:

```
git ls-remote personal_remote
```

Command worked for me on git version **1.9.1**

Answer (score 1):

first git init it directory, then git clone the rep ../../something.git then go into that folder , then try git ls-remote. it should be good.

Answer (score 0):

If using `git` from VS Developer Command Prompt, it helps to change directory to the root of the `git` repository, i.e. the folder that contains the `.git` folder.

Running the `git ls-remote` command from there will pick up the remote repository from the directory.